# How to retrieve game console playing time using. Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, xbox, ps4

I want to build an application that counts playing time for consoles such as Ps4,5 and Xboxes.
I  need to connect somehow the console to .net to retrieve playing time.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there is a user profile you can access that doesn't require connecting to the consoles themselves, rather you could just pull the profile information from the parent company. For example, no need to connect to Xbox if you can just get their profile from Microsoft somehow.

Comment: Yes that's possible for Xbox  (it's a gaming saloon/ shop) but what about PlayStation consoles??

Comment: Have you searched online for any examples? Do you have anything you've tried so far as an example? Your question will most likely get removed in it's current state because you have no examples of what you've tried or researched and it's focus is so broad.

Comment: I just don't care about removing my question I searched and I didn't find anything I just wanted ideas cuz I don't have any to begin with

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps getting profile information from the source, rather than the console, would work for you.

I googled "Microsoft xbox c#" and found that Microsoft has some documentation for Xbox live services [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/live/get-started/live-getstarted-nav).

I googled "Microsoft psn c#" and found that Microsoft also has some documentation for PSN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/playfab/client/authentication/login-with-psn?view=playfab-rest).

Comment: How about PlayStation account